# x is not defined for id = "0" - C3.js stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am getting the error: Uncaught Error: x is not defined for id = "0". When trying to pass data into c3.js timeseries chart.

https://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html

I've tried using the variable in columns as

columns: json_beams 
and json: json_beams

as shown in the code below.

The base code provided from c3.js works fine

Here is the output of my javascript variable json_beams.

Here is how I passed the array to javascript:

```
<script>
  var json_beams = "<?php echo addslashes(json_encode($data1)); ?>";
</script>
```

default timeseries columns:

```
      columns: [
          ['x', '00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00'],
          ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
          ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]
       ]
```

The output of the json_beams variable in console is: (Note: pasting this directly into Columns:' works fine.

```
[["x","00:00:00","01:00:00","02:00:00","03:00:00","04:00:00","05:00:00","06:00:00","07:00:00","08:00:00","09:00:00","10:00:00","11:00:00","12:00:00","13:00:00","14:00:00","15:00:00","16:00:00","17:00:00","18:00:00","19:00:00","20:00:00","21:00:00","22:00:00","23:00:00","24:00:00"],["Beam 0","836","1141","1339","910","655","303","307","211","345","277","235","225","236","239","213","200","190","207","648","937","973","1076","1108","1075"],["Beam 1","913","1152","1333","939","708","326","323","297","394","292","266","244","271","257","231","210","224","190","754","1023","997","1035","1141","1044"]
```

My code:

```
    <script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        xFormat: '%H:%M:%S',
      columns: json_beams
       ]
//         json: json_beams
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%H:%M:%S'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Resulting error is:

Uncaught Error: x is not defined for id = "0".

Regardless of being added to 'columns:' or 'json:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php addSlashes returns a string. In the section 'columns: json_beams' json_beams should be an array of arrays. You will need to convert the string into an array. This tutorial might help: https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/

The reason this worked when you copied and pasted it rather than used a variable is that it was no longer a string.

Comment: @mcook16 - Great! :)